# How to take a href attribute and use it in a div when clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, html, href

In javascript I want to tell `post-container` that when I click on it, take the href located at `link` and go to page X.

> There are multiple `post-container`

My code is this:

```
<div class="post-container">
  <a class="link" href="X">
    <h2 class="post-title">Hello, world!</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="date-posts">...</div>
</div>
```

[image]

> I want to be able to click outside the `Hello, world!` title of my post in any area of ​​`post-container` and go to page X

**Any idea how to do this?**

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Google `addEventListener` and `location + javascript`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a href link for entire div in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465923/a-href-link-for-entire-div-in-html-css)

Comment: What should happen if you click *inside* the `Hello, world!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.Add Event listener to the parent element ([Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)).You can take the `href` property of the child element and then use `window.location.href`.You might need to add `preventDefault()` to avoid default behaviour of `a` tag

If you have multiple tags with same class name.You have to use `querySelectorAll` .Either way if you have single elements or multiple elements with same class name use `querySelctorAll`.

```js
// if you have one tag
let ele = document.querySelectorAll(".post-container")
ele.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let href = element.children[0].getAttribute("href")
    window.location.href = href;

  })

})
```

```css
.post-container {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <a class="link" href="X">
    <h2 class="post-title">Hello, world!</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="date-posts">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Excellent help :)

Comment: @SebastiánVarellaGmz this solution will not work if there are two elements with `post-container` class

Comment: @Āchahms I share a question I asked so you can better understand my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295443/post-clickable-in-blogger

Comment: @Shubh Could you provide me with a solution for multiple `post-container`?

Comment: I already did .It will work for multiple post containers.Updated solution

Answer (score 3):

I hope I'm interpreting your question correctly, but you can just rearrange where you're writing your a href tag.  Instead, wrap your div inside of it.  This will make the entire div element a link.

```
<a class="link" href="google.com">
    <div class="post-container">
        <h2 class="post-title">Hello, World!</h2>
        <div class="date-posts"></div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I did what you suggest, but it doesn't work in my case. I share a question I asked so you can better understand my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295443/post-clickable-in-blogger

Comment: Sebastián Varella Gmz It would work if you managed to do it. The other question is something similar but different, the answer has other considerations. You might want to add a JavaScript onclick event to the div and forget the a, like this `<div onclick="window.location='#';">`

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post-container');

var loadLink = function() {

    var link = this.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].href;

    window.location.href = link;

};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', loadLink, false);
}
```

Check [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gkd6y8vj/)

Comment: Your vanilla JS will only work on the first `.post-container`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have multiple `.post-container`s you would need to iterate over each of them and add an event listener to handle click events. On click, find the `a` get its href and set the window.location (I just console log it in this demo)

```js
(function(){
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".post-container");
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        let el = elems[i];
        el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let href = el.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
            console.log("href",href);
            //window.location.href = href;
        })
    }
})();
```

```html
<div class="post-container">
  <a class="link" href="X">
    <h2 class="post-title">Hello, world!</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="date-posts">...</div>
</div>
<div class="post-container">
  <a class="link" href="Y">
    <h2 class="post-title">Goodbye world!</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="date-posts">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the next error message: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.  In the column 20 of line `for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {`  Please check this link for understand my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295443/post-clickable-in-blogger

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('post-container')[0].onclick = function(e){
  location.href = this.children[0].href;
}
```

Comment: `HTMLCollection` does not have an `onclick` property.

Comment: You forgot an `s` as well...and, what if there are multiple `post-container`?

Comment: If there were multiple then I would have purposed a different solution. That was beyond the scope of the requirement.

Comment: @CodyFortenberry Could you provide me with a solution for multiple  `post-container`?

Comment: @SebastiánVarellaGmz just a simple loop would work. https://jsfiddle.net/8nmqzth5/  other than that I would probably use querySelectorAll as it has a native forEach function.